# Windows 10 Freezing on Waking from Sleep: KB4560960?

Tags: windows-10, freeze, sleep, wake-up

I recently started struggling again with my desktop system (Win10 64 bit, latest patches and updates, no insider ring stuff) freezing when attempting to wake from sleep.

Sometimes, but not always, it never even goes to sleep although the screen shuts down (which is also a behavior that's re-emerged recently).

I thought I had the problem re-solved (not exactly sure how) until it suddenly re-appeared again. Shortly after I installed the KB4560960 update that came out in early June.

I rolled back KB4560960 and things appear to be working normally again.

Has anyone else experienced similar problems?

**Update**

Upgrading to Win10 2004 (aka May 2020 update) appears to have resolved the problem for me, at least with an earlier version of the nVidia GeForce driver. I'm going to try updating to the latest GeForce driver and see what happens.

**Update 2**

So far so good. Updated to the latest nVidia drivers and sleeping/waking properly. Starting to look like it was KB4560960, at least in the context of the pre-May 2020 Win 10 update.

Comment: That update is for V1909 / V1903  .  I did not see the behavior you outline above in my machines.

Comment: Thanx, @John. Are you running v2004 (May 2020)? I haven't been offered that yet. Although I guess I could force the update.

Comment: Yes - since May 27 just past

Comment: Also if you are not offered V2004 yet, you can stay at V1909. KB560960 may not be compatible with your machine

Answer (score 0):

My tablet just got KB4560960 installed. Because it is a tablet it went into sleep mode quite quickly. After that I could not wake it up. It was showing single color filled screen without anything on and was not reacting to power button or windows button presses. Had to hard power off and restart it. Now, I uninstalled KB4560960 and see how it goes. I also suspect KB4560959 causing some issue as it also got installed today.

Update. I uninstalled KB4560960 but it did nor resolve the issue for me. I suspect it is actually caused by KB4560959 security update which cannot be uninstalled?

Comment: That's exactly the pattern I'm observing.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed my Windows 10 Home machine has been doing this for the past month or so.  I don't think Windows is freezing.  However, the screen will not wake up at all after being turned off by power saving and requires a hard boot to get it back.  I used to see this on our work computers and I'm trying to remember the exact fix.  One thing to try could be to turn Off the Fast Startup in the Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > "Choose what the Power Buttons Do" .  Also just make sure your video driver and firmware are up to date.

Comment: Thanx @Aaron. I did those things, and more, first. They're definitely worth trying if anyone else runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with my Dell Inspiron laptop not shutting down properly after selecting "Shutdown".

Screen would turn off but laptop power LED would remain on and laptop would remain hot on the underside. If left overnight it would eventually drain the battery dead flat.

To restart the laptop I would have to hold the power button down for 10 seconds to initiate a hard reboot.

I found the issue was caused by the "Intel Management Engine Interface".  Disabling the IMEI resolved my shutdown issues.

To disable the IMEI go to Computer Management>Device Manager>System Devices, scroll down and click on Intel(R) Management Engine Interface and select "Disable".

I have found that after installing some monthly Microsoft Cumulative updates or any Feature update the IMEI will get re-enabled in which case you have to go and disable again. You could try disabling the IMEI to see if this resolves the Sleep issue.

Answer (score 0):

My version 1903 wouldn't sleep automatically, though it did manually. Uninstalling KB4560960 fixed the sleep problem.

Comment: FYI... Some people state that they are not able to uninstall this update.